# Игнорирование участков кода при debug сборке gradle

Tags: android, gradle

В build.gradle использую

```
...
releaseCompile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1')
releaseCompile('com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1')
releaseCompile('com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1')
...
```

В дебаг версии это все мне не надо и приходится комментировать участки кода и импорты чтоб не было ошибок сборки.
Возможно ли как-то автоматизировать этот процесс, чтоб gradle игнорировал зависимые участки кода и импорты?

Comment: комментируете из-за того что долго билдится?

Comment: Точно, билдится раза в 1.5-2 быстрее.

Comment: Это если проект не большой

Comment: я кстати только что решал эту проблему. Нашел такой вариант: file->settings->build,execution,deployment->gradle и у offline work поставил галочку. Вместо 2,5 минут получил секунд 20 скорости билда

Comment: про offline work и deamon, и про parallel, и про configureondemand знаю :)

Comment: Я так понимаю gradle такое не умеет? Весь  goggle облазил, почти весь :) Окей, буду пользоваться старым добрым комментированием.

Comment: Я других вариантов не нашел=) Вроде бы как это помогло

Comment: Если найдете что - отпишите, вопрос для меня тоже актуальный

Comment: Окей, конечно напишу. Кстати если у вас много оперативки, то попробуйте добавить [это](https://gist.github.com/vseos/3d861006845759e73c803b93e7f498e4)  в gradle.properties (global)